# How to customize $group output in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, grouping

After applying $group stage I get the following result:

```
[
    { 
        _id: { month: 7, day: 19, year: 2018 },
         count: 4 
    }
]
```

Is it possible to apply some another stage and get output like:

```
[
    {
        date: '7-19-2018',
        count: 4
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`$dateFromParts`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromParts/) to convert the date parts into date followed by [`$dateToString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) to convert it to string  in 3.6.

Something like

```
{"$project":{
  "_id":0,
  "date":{
    "$dateToString":{
      "format":"%m-%d-%Y",
      "date":{"$dateFromParts":{"year":"$_id.year","month":"$_id.month","day":"$_id.day"}}
    }
  },
  "count":1
}}
```